# XMatch issue with 2 cell array for search_key parameter

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

Datasets 1 and 2

[image]

| Date | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 | Day 4 | Day 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Andrew | 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 6 |
| Alex | 4 | 3 | 8 | 3 | 2 |
| Chris | 3 | 6 | 7 | 4 | 9 |
| David | 3 | 3 | 6 | 5 | 8 |
| Eric | 3 | 1 | 7 | 3 | 5 |
| Faith | 7 | 4 | 9 | 4 | 8 |
| George | 1 | 3 | 3 | 6 | 7 |
| Harold | 1 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 9 |
| Ian | 9 | 3 | 9 | 7 | 4 |
| Jack | 4 | 5 | 2 | 6 | 8 |
| Larry | 5 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 6 |
| Keith | 4 | 3 | 6 | 5 | 8 |

| Date | Day 1 | Day 3 | Day 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Faith | 7 |  |  |

Using the following 2 tables/datasets, I've managed to get XMATCH to locate a match when the search_key is 3 cells (J1:L1).

- `XMATCH(J26:L26,B26:F26)`

However, when the search_key is set to K1:L1 I get "An array value could not be found."

- `XMATCH(K27:L27,B27:F27)`

Any idea why this is happening?

Understanding why will help me better understand the limitations of the XMATCH function.
Thanks

I've tried playing with a search_key array of various lengths but the issue only occurs when the search_key array has 2 values.

Comment: What is your actual goal? Post data as text table so that we can copy.

Answer (score 2):

XMATCH is a function available only in Excel 2021 or higher so I cannot replicate it but in case you need a different approach easy to implement this may work:

[image]

```
=VLOOKUP($I3,$A$1:$F$13,MATCH(J$2,$A$1:$F$1,0),0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and sorry for not being able to post the actual text data. My bad new to the forum.  Howerver, the work around using VLOOKUP does the trick. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative `MS365` formulas: Using `XLOOKUP()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `J3`

```
=XLOOKUP(
    J2:L2,
    B2:F2,
    XLOOKUP(I3, A3:A14, B3:F14)
)
```

---